# Single, double, triple

Tags: word-request, numbers, numerals

When someone shoots they can hit a target once, twice or three times in a row, and even more times. With one hit we say - single hit, 2 hits - double hit, 3 hits - triple hit. But what are the other ones and do they exist and are they used?

I was thinking of quad hit for 4 but I guess it's wrong.

Comment: Is that really what they say? It seems that *double hit* for example, would mean you hit two targets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words quadruple, quintuple, sextuple, septuple, octuple, and nonuple, all exist, although they get progressively rarer as they get larger. I think quad, as short for quadruple, works fine. – [Peter Shor](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/262/peter-shor)